# Can't type in ipdb console in docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, iterm, ipdb

I'm using docker-compose to build my docker container and am running the container with the `--service-ports` flag like so:

```
docker-compose run --service-ports $(service_name) -d
```

When trying to call ipdb within a python script in the container using `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` ipdb is initialised but I cannot type anything in the console. I also have to manually restart the terminal session in order to stop it (`CTRL+C`, `CTRL+D` etc do nothing). It's not as if the terminal has frozen either as I can still scroll back and on focus / unfocus the cursor changes appearance too.

This is what my term looks like (I use `iTerm`):
[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it boils down to `ipdb` not being compatible with `eventlet.monkey_patch` in the docker container.

Simple fix, switch to `pdbpp` :D

Comment: Unfortunately `pdbpp` is still not properly compatible with Python 3.x, so this workaround doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: Ahh, here's me still working in the ancient land of Python 2.7. At least now we understand it is simply a case-by-case compatibility issue we can explore other options.

Comment: @kevin just for reference: pdbpp is being maintained again since a while, and compatible with py3: https://github.com/antocuni/pdb

Answer (score 1):

Following link worked for me for ipdb too:

https://blog.lucasferreira.org/howto/2017/06/03/running-pdb-with-docker-and-gunicorn.html